# Using javascript to create form and bring input back to php

Tags: javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

Been trying for a while to get this to work. What I want, is when user clicks on `create Card` a form should pop up with multiple fields so they can see `$key[2]` and write a question and answer.

If someone could point me in the right direction to create this form with javascript and explain how to get the variable from that form back to php that would be awesome. I was trying to use `xmlhttprequest`, I don't know if that's best or not.

```php
<?php
if (isset($myNotes)) {
    foreach ($myNotes as $key) {
        Print "<li>$key[2] <a href=''><dif onclick='createCard()'>(Create Card)</dif></a></li>";
    }
}
?>
```

```js
function createCard()
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var question;
    var answer;

    question=prompt("Enter Q:","");
    answer=prompt("Enter Answer:","");

    xmlhttp.open("GET","control.php?q="+question, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a hidden Div that contains the form which when a user clicks on createCard is shown.

```
<div id="popupdiv" style="display:none">
<p>Question: <input type="text" id="question"></p>
<p>Answer: <input type="text" id="answer"></p>
<input type="button" onclick="processCard()">
</div>



function createCard(){

    // This displays the popup with your form.
    document.getElementById("popupdiv").style.display = "block";
}

function processCard(){

    // This grabs the data and sends it server and then hides the div again.
    var question = document.getElementById("question").value;
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","control.php?q="+question+"&a="+answer, true); 
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("popupdiv").style.display = "none";
}   




 <?php
 $question = $_GET['question'];
 $answer = $_GET['answer'];
 ?>
```

Comment: When would I call the processCard function? And wouldn't there be problems since in the php I loop through all the entries (cuz they would all have that same div)? And how would I get the input? Just through a get in control.php?

Comment: The form appears and then before you can type anything goes back to hidden. How do I fix that? Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Also the GET doesn't seem to work. When I submit the form the url doesn't change or anything. It should go to the control with the question/answer input

Comment: Is the processCard function getting called anywhere else, should only be called when the button is clicked?

Comment: k so i figured out why it was disappearing, not sure why but i had the "(create card)" as a link. with that gone works fine. The only prob now is that when i click create card it doesn't do that xml get thing in the control.php file. Why is that? I'm expecting to be able to use the $_GET to get variable in the control page

Comment: When you click on the create card button the form should show, once this is filled in you should click on the processCard button to send the data to your script on the server and then do what ever you want with it.  I might not of understood what you are trying to do, if you stick you code up I should be able to figure out whats wrong.